# Making Ad request when the user is 1-2 scrolls away from the Ad in RecyclerView

Tags: android, admob, android-recyclerview

I have Admob Ads in my RecyclerView and its showing in-between the items in list. Currently, I am calling loadAd method in onbind method of Recycler Adapter. Is there any way we can detect the user is 1-2 scrolls away from the Ad and call loadAd method?

I don't want to call loadAd method in onCreateViewHolder since it will affect fill rate (when we send the ad request and if the user doesn't scroll to Ad to see the Ad it will drop the fill rate)

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(BaseRecyclerHolder baseHolder, int position) {
     ........
     holder.adView.loadAd(adRequest);
 }
```

In this implementation, since the load Ad method is onBindViewHolder, it will be called only when the user has reached the Ad item while scrolling. This may cause some delay in Ad load and the user may not be able to view the Ad and impression will be lost. I want to load this ad request while the user is 2-3 scrolls away from Ad item so that the Ad will be ready when the user reaches Ad item in recycler view

Comment: @SumitShukla : they are in-between recycler view items

Comment: @SumitShukla : I am displaying ads after 5 items, using custom view type logic.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way we can detect the user is 1-2 scrolls away from the
>   Ad and call loadAd method?

Yes you can, by attaching a scroll listener which checks for the last visible child in your RecyclerView using `((LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager()).findLastVisibleItemPosition();` (let's say position is 3, then you're 1 child away from seeing your ad)

That said, it's not required. The RecyclerView already has the View with the Ad preloaded when it's about to get visible to the user. It becomes 'unloaded' (aka recycled with another View) once you scroll over it

Answer (score 0):

i think what you need is this ["Display Admob Banner in RecyclerView"](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ads/tree/master/advanced/BannerRecyclerViewExample) 
it's the right impelentation for this kind of requests.